# Desire HD: I apparently flashed the wrong pd98img.zip, how can I fix this?

Tags: unbricking, fastboot, htc-desire-hd

in a attempt to downgrade my Desire HD from 2.50 to 1.32 I apparently pushed the wrong pd98img.zip into my zip card. I can start the phone, but I'm greeted by some chinese characters and can't do anything but contact emergency numbers. I can't connect the phone with usb, I can't connect with adb or do anything else.

I can get into fastboot by taking out the memory card, otherwise it would try to install the wrong pd98img.zip continouesly.

Right now I have only following informations:

```
Ace PVT SHIP S-ON RL
HBOOT-0.85.0024
MICROP-0438
RADIO-26.09.04.11_M2
eMMC-boot
Apr 12 2011,00:55:45
```

What are my options?